# Delete master record and make it available for old entry only, not new one

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having a problem as described below.

I am developing a form which contains vb.net datagrid with several columns.

Few columns are of comboboxcolumn type which are bound to datasource of SQL Database.

Now when new entry starts, user selects data from different cell of combobox and so on.
Then all rows data from grid is saved to database.

Now if I delete a master record of one table which is the datasource of one column of datagrid,
When I open existing entry list, that particular cell is shown empty because its master data is not available in table.

How do I show deleted master data in existing entry, but not in the new entry?(Obviously it will not be available for new entry)

Answer (score 0):

I would not delete the data... I would have a boolean column for redundancy. Then instead of deleting mark column as redundant = true.

The datagrid I would have with an item and edit template. In the item template would have a label which will be bound to record value. In edit template would have a combobox which would be bound to datasource where redundant = false.